# Python tkinter/sqlite3 programa ignora comparación 'if'

Tags: python, tkinter, bucle-for, condiciones, sqlite3

Tengo que hacer un programa donde tengo que hacer distintos registros en la base de datos de clientes. Los datos de los registros son: Nombre, Apellido, N_cedula y Monto_acumulado. En la función para actualizar un registro, el 'for loop' que tengo aquí abajo verifica que, primero, la entrada (Entry) del número de cédula no esté vacía; y segundo, verifica que el número de cédula exista/esté registrado en la base de datos.

```
def edicion(cdl): # Función de la ventana para realizar cambios a un determinado cliente en la base de datos

    ced = cdl.get()
    # Se comprueba que las entradas de datos tengan contenido válido
    if not ced.strip():
        text_var.set("Asegúrese de ingresar un nro. de cédula válido.")
    else:
        # Los datos obtenidos se almacenan en una tupla
        act_reg = (ced,)
        # Conexión con la base de datos
        conexion = sqlite3.connect('registro_clientes.db')
        # Cursor que ejecutará los comandos
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        # Se seleccionan todos los registros de la base de datos y se almacenan en una variable
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM clientes")
        check = cursor.fetchall()
        # Se itera por todos los registros
        for usuario in check:
            if usuario[0] == ced: # Si el nombre de usuario ya existe, se muestra el siguiente mensaje
                text_var.set("Usuario ya existente.")
                return
            else: # Si el nombre de usuario y la contraseña no existen, se hace un nuevo registro
                pass
```

Al parecer, el código no procesa o ignora la comparación que se hace en el 'if'. Yo utilizo un código muy similar a este en el inicio de sesión del programa, y funciona perfectamente; pero en esta parte del código no. Cabe destacar que el programa es una interfaz de Tkinter. Estaría muy agradecida si me pudieran ayudar con esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque estas editando la variable mal con el bucle for. No entiendo muy bien el funcionamiento del bucle for, pero se que algo anda mal con el, porque esta iterando un objeto binario. Para que sirve el bucle, te puedo ayudar con eso...

Comment: Hola, disculpa que te haya respondido hasta ahora. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo revisé y lo pude corregir. ¡Feliz día!